# Formula to get accurate result from the Data available in Sheet

Tags: excel-formula

I have attached a sheet where i am trying to get this result `(Sheet4(A13:E18))` from data available in `Sheet4(B2:D9)`

I have used some of the formulas but some are really difficult to create someone please can help with the Sheet is attached below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dhvwZgqoCOz5eHAUrROiJK57BIA8g9dmxcps0Hao0ck/edit#gid=584564515

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the data correct. However it's recommended to post your question differently, so not only you are helped, but also people with the same problem can recognize and understand the problem/solution.